# Excel Formula to get desired result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ceil

I have a number like `10.4732`, I want to make this number look like `10.5` in Microsoft excel.

I have used CEILING(Number,2) But it is not working as expected.

Could you please help!

Comment: =Round(Number,1) or .. Roundup / down

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `Round` function in excel

Syntax:

```
ROUND(number, num_digits)
```

The ROUND function syntax has the following arguments:

- number : The number that you want to round.
- num_digits: The number of digits to which you want to round the number argument.

Examples:

```
=ROUND(2.15, 1) is 2.2
```

Rounds `2.15` to one decimal place

```
=ROUND(2.149, 1) is 2.1
```

Rounds `2.149` to one decimal place

For more information please visit https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/round-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Answer (score 0):

You can use round.
Ex:
=ROUND(10.532,1)